# PHP - Routing two controllers with different actions to the same url

Tags: php, routes

I have a route here with one controller linked with one action

```
'car/cars' => [
            'GET' => [
                'controller' => $CarController,
                'action' => 'cars'
            ],
          ]
```

This works perfectly fine for me until I add a second controller with a different action to the same route like so:

```
'car/cars' => [
            'GET' => [
                'controller' => $CarController,
                'action' => 'cars'
            ],
            'GET' => [
                'controller' => $ManufacturerController,
                'action' => 'list'
            ]
        ],
```

My issue is that the first action stops working and the second one starts working. Is there another way I can route two different actions to the `car/cars` url? I have tried the method below which gives me the same result

```
        'car/cars' => [
            'GET' => [
                'controller' => $CarController,
                'action' => 'cars'
            ],
        ],
        'car/cars' => [
            'GET' => [
                'controller' => $ManufacturerController,
                'action' => 'list'
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - if two different controller methods correspond to the same path, which one would you expect to happen if someone visited that URL? For reference, the reason both of these fail is that you're setting the same key more than once in an array - the last instance will always overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: @iainn If someone visited that URL, i want both the actions to execute. For eg, the action linked to `list` is displaying manufacturers and the action `cars` is responsible for listing cars.

I now understand that its setting the same key more than once, is there a way around this or a method for this?

Comment: add a third, that it self runs list and cars, assuming you want to keep those seprate as well

Comment: You don't say what your actions do (or which routing library you're using if any), but assuming these actions generate webpages, are you just expecting two entire HTML pages to be output one after the other? Each route needs to correspond to a *single* action, which can then do as much or as little as you need.

Comment: @iainn I'll try and be a bit more clear sorry. The action `cars` leads to a seperate php controller (this file is connected to cars table) which contains a function called "cars" that will run. This function runs a  `SELECT FROM` which displays all cars.

The action `list` is connected to a manufacturers php file which does the same thing and runs a `SELECT FROM` but displays manufacturers on a sidebar. 

These are screenshots of the two functions on the controllers files: https://imgur.com/a/3SRj5

This allows me to use the $manu and $cars variable to view manufacturers and cars.

Comment: So the classes `Manufacturer` and `Car` are your controllers or your models?

Comment: @AmrAly correct, controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `$manufactorerTable` into your `Car` controller like so:

```
class Car {

  private $carsTable;
  private $manufactorerTable;

  public function __constructor($carsTable, $manufactorerTable) {
    $this->carsTable = $carsTable;
    $this->manufactorerTable = $manufactorerTable;
  }

  public function cars() {
    $cars = $this->carsTable->findAll();
    $manufactorer = $this->manufactorerTable->find('manufactorerid', 1)[0];

    return [
      ...
      'variables': [
        'cars' => $cars,
        'manufactorer' => $manufactorerTable
      ]
    ];
  }
}
```

and of course you will need only one route for this action which is:

```
'car/cars' => [
      'GET' => [
          'controller' => $CarController,
          'action' => 'cars'
      ],
 ]
```

Comment: Hey I tried this method received the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function PreControllers\Controllers\Car::__construct(), 1 passed in /srv/http/cars/PreControllers/Routes.php on line 13 and exactly 2 expected in /srv/http/cars/PreControllers/Controllers/Car.php on line 10` 

This is the section on my routes.php https://i.imgur.com/hNXQ1hx.png . Been trying to debug this for a few mins but cannot figure out what is out of place

Comment: modify the `$carController` to accept two arguments instead of one `($carsTable, $manufacturerTable)`

Comment: modify `$carController` in `/srv/http/cars/PreControllers/Routes.php` so it's `$carController = new \PreControllers\Controllers\Car($carsTable, $manufacturerTable);`

Comment: This worked for me after the modify, thank you so much I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
 'car/cars' => [
        'GET' => [
            'controller' => $CarController,
            'action' => 'listCars' // new method to implement
        ],
    ],
```

Problem solved :)